# Countifs onto a master dataset from multiple data frames

Tags: r

I've got a master dataset (all_members). It has one row per person. I've got 25ish other data tables that members may or may not be listed on, 1+ times. I"m using R Studio.

I want to create a new variable on all_members for each of the additional data tables, and then do a countif counting how many times the member is shows up for each of the variables on the other data tables.

In excel, I'd do a combo vlookup + countif. How do I accomplish this in R Studio?

Comment: Please include your data with your question. You can use `dput(all_members)` to include code on how to make your dataset.

Comment: Ok - I need to create a de-identified set. Just a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Overview

The following answer relies on reproducible data I made that counts the number of students in a particular class. These counts are added as new columns to the master data set, named `all.students`.

The use of [`sum()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) in the anonymous function inside of [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) is flexible so that it counts `ID` values that appear multiple times in different data sets. While `math.class` and `history.class` only have one unique student per data  set, `detention` contains the same student multiple times. These counts are reflected in the final output.

## Reproducible Example

This reproducible example ensures that the values in `all.student$ID` are unique.

This answer relies on manually creating (and naming) and list with the separate `ID` columns from the other tables. You use that list as your `X` argument when counting how many times your individual students in `all.students` appeared in each table. The use of [`cbind.data.frame()`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.1.1/doc/html/Language_Reference/base/cbind.data.frame.html) column binds `all.students` with `count.ID.in.other.tables` to add those counts as columns into `all.students`.

```
# create data
all.students <- 
  data.frame( ID = 1:10
              , Gender = sample( x = c( "F", "M"), size = 10, replace = TRUE )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# ensure all.students
# only contains one row for each unique value in `ID` column
all.students <- 
  all.students[ which( !duplicated( x = all.students$ID ) ) , ]

# check dim
dim( all.students )
# [1] 10  2

# three data frames
# one for each class
math.class <-
  data.frame( ID = c( 2:4, 6:7)
              , Grade = c( "A", "B", "C", "A", "C" )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

history.class <-
  data.frame( ID = c( 1, 8:10)
              , Grade = rep( x = "A", times = 4 )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

detention <-
  data.frame( ID = rep( x = 5, times = 3)
              , Date = as.Date( x = c( "2017-12-01"
                                       , "2018-01-23"
                                       , "2018-02-14"
              )
              )
              , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# create list
# containing each `ID` column
# from each table not named `all.students`
ID.in.other.table <-
  list( detention = detention$ID
        , history.class = history.class$ID
        , math.class = math.class$ID
        )
# view list
ID.in.other.table
# $detention
# [1] 5 5 5
# 
# $history.class
# [1]  1  8  9 10
# 
# $math.class
# [1] 2 3 4 6 7

# count how many times each member
# appears in the other data frames
count.ID.in.other.tables <-
  lapply( X = ID.in.other.table
          , FUN = function( i )
            sapply( X = all.students$ID,
                    FUN = function( j ) 
                      sum( i == j )
            )
  )

# view list
count.ID.in.other.tables
# $detention
# [1] 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# $history.class
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
# 
# $math.class
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0

# combine vectors in list
# and add to all.students
all.students <-
  cbind.data.frame(
    all.students
    , do.call(
      what = cbind
      , args = count.ID.in.other.tables
    )
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# check dim
dim( all.students ) # [1] 10  5

# view data
all.students
#    ID Gender detention history.class math.class
# 1   1      F         0             1          0
# 2   2      M         0             0          1
# 3   3      M         0             0          1
# 4   4      M         0             0          1
# 5   5      F         3             0          0
# 6   6      F         0             0          1
# 7   7      M         0             0          1
# 8   8      F         0             1          0
# 9   9      F         0             1          0
# 10 10      M         0             1          0

# end of script #
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now... to make sure I can reproduce with my own data. Thank you tahnk you.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

`> all_member_list_for_dynamic_engagement_2_6_18_50k_no_nulls[ which( colnames( all_member_list_for_dynamic_engagement_2_6_18_50k_no_nulls ) %in% new.column.names ) ][] <-
+     do.call( what = cbind, args = count.salesforce_ids.in.other.df )

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  : 
  replacement has 487071 items, need 529425`

Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlissaSwartz I apologize but I've revised my answer to be less verbose. I was opening the door to too many unforeseen errors. Please let me know what you think of the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this but it depends on what your data looks like. It may be possible to simply join all the tables into a single dataframe and simply:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name) %>% tally()
```

If the data can not be combined into a single df because of differences in the data then it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: I don't know if I"m following. Where is the reference provided across the DFs?

i.e. all_members (DF1) and current_members (DF2), shared unique ID. I want to count the number of times the unique ID shows in DF2 and add that count as a cell on a new variable on DF1. 

I am not sure how to enter an example but here's what I want: 

DF1: all_members
Unique ID  count_unique_id_df2

Comment: If you provide us with a working example, we can trouble shoot your issue. Currently it's all very abstract  (for both of us).